# How to retrieve objects from foreign key relation in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

so I am trying to retrieve my **Post** object from my ***Bookmark** model which is based on a base model. However, it seems it is always returning null, and I was wondering how can I retrieve my post oject?

This is my bookmark model:

```
class BookmarkBase(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="User")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class BookmarkPost(BookmarkBase):
    class Meta:
        db_table  = "bookmark_post"
    
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    obj = models.ForeignKey('home.Post',on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Post")
```

and in my `views.py` I have the query:

`posts = BookmarkPost.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)` However, it is not returning anything although I do have posts bookmarked. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

I have tested the query above using `posts.count()` and it returns `3` which is the number of posts my logged in user has bookmarked, however inside my template I have:

```
{% for post in posts %}
      {{ post.title }}
{% empty %}
      is empty
{% endfor %}
```

Which does not even return `is empty` right now.

My views.py:

```
@login_required
def bookmarks(request):
    posts = BookmarkPost.objects.filter(user__id=request.user.id)
    context = {
        'posts':posts,
    }
    return render(request,'main/bookmark/bookmarks_user.html', context)
```

And my profile model:

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    bio = models.TextField()
    university = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(default='defaults/user/default_u_i.png', upload_to=upload_to_uuid('profile_image/profiles/'), blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "{}".format(self.slug)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you have bookmarks for the user that has been logged in? Having bookmarks is *not* sufficient, if these are for other users, then it will indeed return an empty set.

Comment: yes when I printed `posts.count()` it did return an integer greater than 0 meaning there are bookmarks however when I loop through `post` objects it returns nothing

Comment: `post` or `posts`. Can you verify that the name you pass to the context is the same one in the `{% for ... %}` loop?

Comment: Furthermore is `profile` your `AUTH_USER_MODEL`, can you share the `Profile` model? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have added my `views`, `Profile` model and example of what I ran in my template as well.

Comment: does post have a title property? You are calling ```{{ post.title }}``` but I do not see that BookPost has a title.

Comment: Yes inside the Post model it does have a title property

Comment: Are you sure that `post.title` is not empty in those post? ... Add some string before the title, just to check that, something liket this `{% for post in posts %} Title:  {{ post.title }} {% empty %} is empty {% endfor %}`

Comment: in your {{post.title}} where are you getting that title field cause i dont see it anywhere in you model

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how I can access the field of every **Post** object that is saved using the foreign key in the **BookmarkPost** model.

So for getting the `bookmark` objects inside my view I have to do:

```
user = request.user
bookmarked_posts = user.bookmarkpost_set.all()
```

Which will give the `bookmark` objects (Not the post objects). And then in my template, I can simply do:

```
{% for bookmark in bookmarked_posts %}

   {{ bookmark.obj.title }}

{% endfor %}
```

Which will give me the title of all the posts that my user has bookmarked.